# Install wordpress plugin/theme using Python Script

Tags: php, python, wordpress

I am trying to upload some plugins/theme on my website, that is based on Wordpress. I checked all the WordPress API keys, but none of them working the same thing that I want. Is there possible to upload and activate plugins/Themes on WordPress without using any plugin(Just with the help of WordPress username and password)? Actually what am I trying to do is that:

By running script

1. It asks for Web URL: i.e https://example.com/wp-admin
2. then it asks for username and password
3. and then Plugin/Theme starts
   upload from the directory(Where my plugin and themes are placed).

if there any kind of example like this, please comment on this post. Thanks